My MoreLogin .exe file isn't starting even after installing wine
enter image description hereI am unable to use my .exe file even after I installed wine on my Debian 12. The application is not starting, even if it does, it closes up immediately. I also tried installing PlayOnLinux on my Debian but keep getting this error message below:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
playonlinux : Depends: python but it is not installable
Depends: python-wxgtk2.8 but it is not installable or
python-wxgtk3.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

This question is unclear, and questions about Debian are off topic at Ask Ubuntu.

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

python     | 2.7.16-1      | oldoldstable | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386
